# Do you need redux for a multiuser Reactjs app?

Tags: java, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Have maybe a naive question but really I could not find a straight forward answer when would you prefer Redux over React Hooks.
I am new to Reactjs and curently I am working on a multiuser, blog, onlineshop app for a clinet. The project has two phases:
Phase 1 - Involved just CRUD interaction with the Firebase DB
but
Phase 2 - Will have multiuser system and an onlineshop - sell games based on a per user point earning system from watching adds and posting blogs.
Now, phase 1 was easy and React Context hook was enought but now I wander will React Hooks be enough for the phase2 or will I have to speand time and learn Redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the application becomes more complex, I would advise switching to redux.

In redux, the component subscribes to several states and will re-render only when those states change.

In context, every component has the entire context object, and will re-render even when unrelated state is changed.

If performance is not a priority, you can use stick to context.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Context does not separate what happened (for example user clicks save) with what the app needs to do when this happens (for example save some data) and how to get the result data (for example failed, succeeded with data).

In redux all of these things are seperated;

- something happened: dispatch an action
- implement when something happened: reducers and middleware
- component or middleware needs status of saving something: selectors

The patterns redux uses are event store that can be used in redux-devtools to replay a bunch of actions after changing reducers to see if you fixed a problem and CQRS that separates writing to state with getting state values causing loosely coupled code and better reusability.

Redux has more abstraction and takes longer to set up but will make it easier to implement complex requirements (if you know what you're doing) and maintain your project.

Context prevents props drilling and is easy to implement simple requirements but will make it harder as your project grows in complexity.